# CSS invert the element but leave background images inside

Tags: javascript, css

To **invert** whole website colors, I can use:

```
body {
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

And to **escape images and videos** from the color inversion, I can use:

```
body img, body iframe, body video {
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

But I ***can't escape the background images from inversion***.

Any CSS or JS workaround for that?

Comment: Can you target specific elements that don't have background images for inversion, instead of targeting the whole body?

Comment: I would fix the logic instead. Applying filter to the whole page is a bad idea. Consider using different class where you define different coloration for your elements. Read about "dark/light mode" and you will find a lot of ideas.

Comment: I can find the elements with background images, but there a lot of those, therefore, I am looking for a quick solution. Just like above is a couple of lines of code that is doing it except the background images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would do it this way as it is cancelling a filter put on an element you do not want in the first place by reapplying it but, using JS you could query all elements using `document.querySelectorAll('*')` and then run this nodeList through a loop and check `getComputedStyle(tag).backgroundImage`, check to see if these do not equal `"none"`, if not you have a tag with a background-image property applied to it. Then you can style tag using JS.

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('*')
all.forEach(tag => {
  if(getComputedStyle(tag).backgroundImage !== 'none'){
    // these are elements with CSS background-image properties applied to them
    tag.style.filter = "invert(100%)";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
    filter: invert(100%);
}


body img, body iframe, body video {
    filter: invert(100%);
}

.sect {
  background-image: url("https://www.hoglezoo.org/wp-content/themes/hoglezoo_new/images/animal_finder/706915056Lion2.jpg");
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Nature%20and%20Landscape/Beautiful_Sunrising_Nature_Image.jpg">

<div class="sect"></div>
```

Rather than add a filter to the body and then reapply the filter to cancel the filter. You can use JS and create an array of restricted tags, then query all the selectors on the page and check if the ***array*** does not include the elements `tagName`. Then apply the filter to elements not in the array. Then you can check the tags not within your restricted array with `getComputedStyle(tags).backgroundImage`, this should *filter* out the remaining elements with a css property of background-image set.

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('*')

const restricted = ["html", "body", "head", "style", "script", "style", "img", "video", "iframe"]

all.forEach(tags => {
  if (!restricted.includes(tags.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
    if (getComputedStyle(tags).backgroundImage === 'none') {
      // these are elements with CSS background-image properties applied to them
      tags.style.filter = "invert(100%)";
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.text {
  color: red;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.image {
   background-image: url('http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/sun-through-fall-foliage-190x190.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   text-align: center;
   width: 190px;
   height: 190px;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img class="fit-picture" src="https://www.planjourney.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Mizoram.jpg">
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="image">This div has an image for background, text is white</div>
<div class="box">This is a blue box with white text, will be inverted 100%</div>
<p class="text">Here is some red text in a p tag that will be inverted 100%</p>
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
</iframe>
```